# How do I move this chat layout(black one) to right side with the help of java code?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

How do I move this chat layout(black one) to right side with the help of java code?

I'm making a chat app and i want the message sent by me in the right side and msg sent by another person in the left side(as shown in the screenshot)

[image]

the code of my chat layout is:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/message_single_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/message_profile_layout"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:src="@drawable/default_profile" />

        <com.daasuu.bl.BubbleLayout
            android:id="@+id/message_bubble_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/message_profile_layout"
            android:padding="8dp"
            app:bl_arrowDirection="left"
            app:bl_arrowHeight="8dp"
            app:bl_arrowPosition="12dp"
            app:bl_arrowWidth="8dp"
            app:bl_bubbleColor="@color/black"
            app:bl_cornersRadius="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="2dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/message_text_layout"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                    android:text="Message Here"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/time_view_layout"
                    android:layout_width="32dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="00:00"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </com.daasuu.bl.BubbleLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>'
```

Comment: I can't see any relation to "java code"

Comment: Just use 2 viewHolderds different. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create two `viewholders` for this, which will have different layouts according to the user type.  [Look at this answer on how to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type)
You will basically select the viewType on the basis of message, whether the user is self or other, and accordingly show the appropriate view.